How to allow ':' character in Node.js Express routes (Google custom methods)
I found a Google "recommendation" about REST custom methods, that seems to me very useful
https://cloud.google.com/apis/design/custom_methods
How to allow the ':' character in Node.js routes without matching it as a named parameter?
Tried with something like
app.post('/item\:method'
but this has strange results, this matches everything starting with /item ...
Also tried with
app.post('/item\\:method'
but I get
SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^\/item\(?:([^\/]+?))\/?$/i: Unmatched ')'

To allow the colon (:)enter code herein Node.js routes without treating it as a parameter, you can escape the colon using a double backslash.
app.post('/item[:]method', (req, res) => {
// Handle request here

});

Does not work, I get
SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^/item(?:([^/]+?))/?$/i: Unmatched ')'

app.post('/item[ :]method')

By using a character class that includes a space and a colon ( [ :], you are telling Node.js to match the space or colon character exactly. This way, the character :is not interpreted as a named parameter.

ok works. Please update the answer, thanks
